# Installing an offline html app and data onto an iPad

Tags: html, ios, ipad, file-transfer

I am contemplating buying an iPad and am wondering what options I will have for developing an app for personal use ... specifically whether I will be able to do it as an offline browser app. The app currently exists as an Android Java app; it interacts with a large local database (about 3MB) and displays images and text drawn from a very large pool of resources stored locally (about 2GB).

My immediate questions are:

1. How would I get the files (html/javascript, database, images and text) transferred into the iPad's storage from a Windows PC? With Android this is a simple matter of hooking up via USB and using Windows Explorer. Googling suggests that for an iPad I might have to use an app on Windows called DiskAid, but this costs $25 which seems a bit steep for my simple purpose. Are there free alternatives?
2. Once the files are installed on the iPad how would I run the html app? On Android this appears to be a matter of keying "file:///sdcard/MyBrowserAppFolder/mybrowserapp.htm" into the browser's address box. Does th iPad browser work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic kinds of applications that run on iOS.

1. Mobile designed web applications that are hosted on a server and accessed through Safari or another browser.
2. Native applications built using Xcode and usually objective-c.

For the latter, you could use the phonegap framework to build an app using existing html and javascript.

My personal advice is to invest the time to learning how to code this up using objective-c.  Depending on what format your db is in, importing the structure and data might be trivial.  It will take an investment of time, but doing things using the native tools is the best choice for iOS development in my opinion.  I was in the same situation (PHP, VB.NET and Javascript developer) and just decided to take the time and learn to do it right.  This was a great decision and the development time of a simple to moderate application takes very little time now.

Comment: Doesn't objective-c development require ownership of a Mac? I understand what you say about doing it right

Comment: (Sorry my edit timed out ... this is what I intended to write ...) 1. How would I use a server-hosted app offline? 2. Is Phonegap a practical proposition where the app together with its data comes to 2GB or more (and where I will want to add to the data from time to time)? 3. Doesn't objective-c development require ownership of a Mac? (I understand what you say about doing it right ... I have learned a lot from doing it in Java for Android.)

Comment: Using XCode to develop an iOS app does require a Mac.  You can't use a server hosted web application offline.  Phonegap and the size of the project really aren't related.  Phonegap is a framework that allows you to build an iOS app using html and javascript.  While not near as flexible as a native iOS app (you don't have access to the mobile substrate for example), it is one solution for those who don't want to do things using objective-c

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. The point of my question about Phonegap is that, so far as I can see, the thing that Phonegap produces is delivered to the user's device over the internet and the only offline storage is in the browser's cache, so I presume that this is not practical for my requirement which is to have an app which will work with 2GB of data entirely offline. It seems I'll have to stick with Android :(

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iOS does not support the URL's of type `file://` natively.  So you either write your own app, purchase an app or use something like [a local web server](http://www.nitroware.org/apache/unofficial-fully-functional-web-server-for-ios) after jailbreaking.

Alternatively, and if you can verify that the app you have mentioned does what you want to do, then maybe $25 is not so much of a price. Depends on what your time is worth :)

However there are cheaper apps around that allow to transfer and read html via wifi and usb. (Not sure I can name them here)

The USB transfer aka `iTunes Filesharing` is a standard function that a developer can enable in the info.plist of their app. Many apps use this to transfer data between Computer and iDevice.

Comment: 1. The reason for buying an iPad would be to get something that would be simple to use in the Apple-approved way, so my feeling is that jailbreaking and installing a local server would defeat the purpose. 2. If the browser won't run local html apps I would have no need for a file transfer app. 3. Am I right in thinking that info.plist is part of an objective-C app? If so, that route would be no use to me without a Mac :(

Comment: re 2.) You need the local web server to circumnavigate the issue with the lack of file:// schema support. The local web server would load the local file, that you would have transferred earlier and Safari can open pages (even local one) using http://. re. 3.) To program you officially need a mac there are ways to do on a PC but seeing you are not happy with jailbreaking this might not be for you. I have edited my answer wrt Filesharing

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping offline browser apps would provide a relatively easy way for me to use my app on different platforms. It seems as if it won't be as straightforward as I had hoped, so I'll probably stick with Android for the time being. However, I will bear in mind your interesting suggestions.